# VBoxManage equivalent for VMware Workstation Pro

Tags: vmware-workstation

Is there a command line tool for create and modify virtual machines with VMWare Workstation Pro?

I.e. something like VirtualBox's `VBoxManage.exe` with `VBoxManage.exe createvm ...`, `VBoxManage.exe modifyvm ...` etc.

VMware has `VMware PowerCLI` but AFAIK it does not work with WMware Workstation Pro.

Comment: Does vmrun work? https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vix160_vmrun_command.pdf

Comment: @SathyajithBhat: vmrun still exists - you should put up an answer.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat: AFAICS vmrun does not have commands for create or modify vms.